# Changing size of popup on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

Is there any kind of way to change the size of the popup that ArcGIS Online displays in the maps/apps?

I want it so that there is no scrolling required to view the picture/thumbnail at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

According to an ESRI source, there is still no way to resize a popup window in ArcGIS Online.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/138840

Hopefully (with the newest line of releases and ESRI's emphasis on "webmaps can do everything that Desktop can do"), we will see an update.